# Unable to use Hwndsource in my code

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0

I am building a C# app in .net 4.0. For some reason I can't make this code work:

```
HwndSource Source;

Source = HwndSource.FromHwnd(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle);
Source.AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(Window_Proc));
```

Can't seem to import the correct assembly.

Comment: What error are you getting?  What is "this" class a subclass of?

Comment: I am using the code at the bottom of my Formload event. Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're doing this inside of a Windows Forms Form class, you can just override [WndProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc%28v=vs.100%29) instead of trying to use an `HwndSource` and a hook.

Comment: Thanks Reed, I am looking into this!